# how to read and save time a user went offline in a discord server

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

what I want to do is that everytime a user goes offline the time he gets offline gets saved in a json file. I know how to save it in a json and all that but what I dont know is, how do I save the time and how do I check when people go offline. thx for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
import time

@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if str(before.status) == "online":
        if str(after.status) == "offline":
            timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
            print("{} has gone {} at date-time {}.".format(after.name,after.status,timestr))
```

This will print something like:

`JackMoody has gone offline at 20190621-155145`

Every time a user's status goes from "online" to "offline".

Comment: really thx a lot. ill try to write it so it saves it on a json cuz i want that information to be on a userinfo. but yea you really helped me out

Comment: Hey Im 1 year and 5 months late but I have a question

Comment: nvm i figured it out

Comment: @TroyD consider upvoting if this helped :D